# Is there a JavaScript function (vanilla or library is fine) that is equivalent to R stats::optimize?

Tags: javascript, r, optimization

I am working on converting an R package into Javascript for a side project. The R code uses the R stats function optimize, [documentation here.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/optimize)

I've tried googling quite a bit but the word optimize really pollutes the search results unfortunately. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm not a stats / math whiz, so it's difficult for me to independently implement or evaluate other implementations. I'm looking for an easily used, pre-built function from a respected / well-maintained library, ideally.

Comment: "looking for a library" is off topic for SO, but (as mentioned on Twitter), I believe the algorithm used by optimize() is also called "Brent's method", which might help in searching